# Number of Longest increasing subsequence

Tags: c#, java, c++, c

I need to return the number of `LIS` of the array.

Pseudocode example:

```
if the arr is
 int []arr = {2,4,90,-3,-2,-1,-10,-9,-8};
num of LIS is: 3
 2,4,90
 -3,-2,-1
 -10,-9,-8
```

example 2:

```
arr [] = {2,-3,4,90,-2,-1,-10,-9,-8};
num of LIS is: 4
2,4,90
-3,4,90
-3,-2,-1
-10,-9,-8
```

I have tried to do this:

```
int [] A = {2,4,90,-3,-2,-1,-10,-9,-8};
    int[] dp = new int[A.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        dp[i] = 1;

        for (int j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++) {
            if (A[j] < A[i]) {
                dp[i] = dp[i] + dp[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(dp[dp.length - 1] ) ;
    }
```

Comment: what problem are you facing ?

Comment: You should try to find the min val and then  assign it

Comment: You can probably brute force this in quadratic time.

Comment: @Zom-B You can find *all* of the complete increasing subsequences in linear time, since each starts after the end of the previous one.  There's no need to "start back from the beginning" to find the next increasing subsequence, which is what would make it quadratic time.

Comment: Why is '2,4,90' a increasing subsequence of {2,-3,4,90,-2,-1,-10,-9,-8}? Surely is stopped increasing at -3?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site for doing your homework for you. This isn't a question, this is a list of facts.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you just keep on adding to the dp[i] for all lookups in the inner for loop. Ideally you should find the maximum size of the subsequence for all positions (j < i) and then add that maximum Value to d[i]. 
Correct way is as follows :

```
int maxSizeOfSubseq = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    dp[i] = 1;
    maxSizeOfSubseq = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++) {
        if (A[j] < A[i] && dp[j] > maxSizeOfSubseq ) {
            maxSizeOfSubseq = dp[j];
        }
    }
    dp[i] = dp[i] + maxSizeOfSubseq ;
             System.out.println(dp[dp.length - 1] ) ;
}


// Now find the Max Size Of Subsequence amongst all computes subsequence lengths
maxSizeOfSubseq  = 0;
for(int count = 0 ; count < dp.length; ++count)
{
  if(dp[i] > maxSizeOfSubseq )
  {
  maxSizeOfSubseq  = dp[i]
  }
}

return maxSizeOfSubseq ;
```

Comment: it's not working..take example arr [] = {2,-3,4,90,-2,-1,-10,-9,-8};
need to return 4 
the methud return 3

Comment: Are you sure it should be 4? Looks like there are 3  increasing subsequences, all lengths 3, 2 and 3, to me: -3, 4, 90; -2, -1; -10, -9, -8.

Comment: [2,4,90]
,
 [-3,4,90]
,
[ -3,-2,-1]
,
[ -10,-9,-8]

Thanks but..it is still not working..

Comment: You're mixing the examples. I also only see 3 subsequences. Please clarify the data to be used.

Comment: @agamoti what issue are u facing..did yoou try to debug it ?